# flutter pushReplacement method is reopening previous screen

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using pushReplacement() to move to next screen while replacing my old screen. I have screen of logout where I'm calling signOut() function of Google Auth of Firebase but which when pressing on device's back button it open home page of application.

Code

```
void signOut(context) {
    final googleCurrentUser = fireAuth.currentUser;
    if (googleCurrentUser != null) {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const SplashScreen(),
            transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(
              opacity: a,
              child: c,
            )));
        // googleSignIn.signOut().then((value) {
        //   fireAuth.signOut().then((value) {
        //
        //   });
        // });
      });
    }
  }
```

Here I have Posted my SplashScreen code for refrence

SplashScreen Code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:app/screens/email_verification.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SplashScreenState();
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    // Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete(() => (checkLogin()));
    if(mounted) {
      checkLogin();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/logo.gif',
            gaplessPlayback: false,
            repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
      ),
    ));
  }

  checkLogin() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      debugPrint("Current User -= -= -= -= -= -= -= -= -= -= ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}");
      if(!FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.emailVerified) {
        if(mounted) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(PageRouteBuilder(
              pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const EmailVerification(),
              transitionDuration:
              const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) =>
                  FadeTransition(
                    opacity: a,
                    child: c,
                  )));
        } else {
          debugPrint("IS EMAIL VERIFIED MOUNTED 0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0 FALSE");
        }
      }
      Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () =>
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              PageRouteBuilder(
                  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const HomeScreen(),
                  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(
                    opacity: a,
                    child: c,
                  )),)
      );
    } else {
      Timer( const Duration(seconds: 3), () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              PageRouteBuilder(
                  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const SignIn(),
                  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(
                    opacity: a,
                    child: c,
                  )),)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `SplashScreen()` code updating your question ?

Comment: @ItzDavi I have updated it.

Comment: Did you check if your `checkLogin()` in `SplashScreen()` isn't responsible of your problem ? It could be that function that opens again the `HomeScreen()`

Comment: @ItzDavi when I move to __**SplashScreen()**__ logically it will check if user is logged in or not. at that time __**FirebaseAuth.instance.currentuser**__ is null and it moves on __**SignIn()**__ screen but when I press back button on device then it will move to again __**HomeScreen()**__